# GA BigQuery: Are you able to query total 'page views' of a specific page view?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Using the GA UI I am able to view how many users viewed a specific "page view" that is being fired. Is it possible to find this data in big query as well?

```
  totals.pageviews
```

Gives me the over all page views during a session but my interest is in a specific page view.

From reading the export schema I know I can query for a specific page path but there is no mention of a specific page view.

--Using Legacy SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. Here's probably the most efficient way of doing so:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(1)
FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_tableid`
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'/home/') AND type = 'PAGE')
```

This example counts how many customers visited a page whose path had '/home/' somewhere.

Notice this counts total users and not total page views. If a customer saw the same page twice it still counts as 1.

This query gives the total page views:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SUM((SELECT COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'/home/')) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE'))
FROM `dataset.ga_sessions_tableid`
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagepath, r'/home/') AND type = 'PAGE')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using legacy SQL. What is the purpose of UNNEST(hits) in this query? Again thanks a lot for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @WilliamKnighting I highly recommend to migrate your query to the [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) version in BQ. `UNNEST` is the operation to basically open an ARRAY and get the inner values. By using standard you have much better control over how data is handled as opposed to legacy that tries to do flattening automatically for you (and ends up duplicating unnecessarily lots of data).

Comment: @WilliamFuks Thanks a lot for the advice. Do you suggest a particular resource to use for making the transition or just stick to reading the google docs?

Comment: @WilliamKnighting Glad to know it worked :). I find the BQ official docs already quite good (in fact it's one of the best docs I've seen, you can literally learn everything there's to BQ there). Funny thing is that you'll find SO answers on BQ tag another valuable source of information, specially answers from Elliott and Mikhail, you can learn quite advanced techniques following their answers (in fact what I did (and still do) when learning about BQ).

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of page views for a specific page, use this:

```
select hits.page.pagePath , count(*)
from [<insert data set name>]
where
  hits.type='PAGE' and
  hits.page.pagePath = '<insert page path>'
group by hits.page.pagePath
```